# Docusign REST API Changing textTabs in a template

Tags: docusignapi

I am having trouble updating textTabs when creating an envelope using the rest API (v2).

The json I'm sending looks like this :

```
{
   "status": "sent",
   "emailSubject": "Yet another text 13:57",
   "templateId": "xxxxxxx-4dcb-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
   "templateRoles": [
     {
       "name": "Persons Name",
       "email": "me@me.com",
       "roleName": "Signer",
       "tabs": {
         "textTabs": [
           {
             "tabLabel": "ClientName",
             "value": "My Name"
           },
           {
             "tabLabel": "ClientAddress",
             "value": "This will be the client address"
           },
           {
             "tabLabel": "PhoneNumber",
             "value": "+1 555 123 4561"
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   ]
 }
```

I have textTabs in the template identified with the template ID with tabLabels set to ClientName, etc.
However - when POSTING the JSON above, the text in the template tabLabels is not replaced.

How do I Change text in TextLabel tabs when creating an envelope in JSON?

Comment: This should correctly update the tab values. Can you please share your templateId. Are you sure your template has the same tab labels?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you are providing the correct tab labels in your request.

You can confirm the name of the tabLabels using the [GetTemplateRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateRecipients/list/) api

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients?include_tabs=true
```

Comment: Rolename was wrong. I added an answer for other people.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure that the Role used to add the tabs (this is in the top right of the document entry page), is the same as the TemplateRole detailed in the RoleName attribute of your posted JSON.